# Embedded Qualtrics: detect the end of survery on parent window

Tags: javascript, iframe, qualtrics

I am using iframe to embed a Qualtrics survey into my website.
I want to show a div (hidden on load) on the parent website only after users complete the survey.
Is it possible for the parent website to detect when users have finished the survey?

I have looked at [Qualtrics API document](https://api.qualtrics.com/82bd4d5c331f1-qualtrics-java-script-question-api-class) but it doesn't seem like such a method exists.

So far, I have made a connection between my website and embedded iframe by the [JS function postMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) like this:

```
//parent website
<iframe class="iframe" src="https://xxx.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/xxx"></iframe>
<div class="hello" style="display: none;">hello</div>

<script>
  window.addEventListener('message', (e) => {
    if(e.origin.includes("https://xxx.qualtrics.com")){
      document.querySelector('.hello').style.display = 'block';
    }
  });
</script>
```

```
//Qualtrics iframe JS file
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnReady(function(){
    // need to detect when the survey ends here
    // if(xyz) {
    parent.postMessage('survey ended', 'http://flovitamins.com');
    // }
});
```

But I am unsure how I can detect the end of the survey on the Qualtrics side and tell the parent website.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I figured it out.

Qualtrics runs this JS line of code when the survey ends automatically (not written in custom JS section)

```
parent.postMessage('QualtricsEOS|SURVER_ID|XXX', '*');
```

So all I need to do on the parent website is:

```
<iframe class="iframe" src="https://xxx.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SURVER_ID"></iframe>
<div class="hello" style="display: none;">hello</div>

<script>
  window.addEventListener('message', (e) => {
    if(e.origin.includes("https://xxx.qualtrics.com") && e.data.includes('QualtricsEOS|SURVER_ID')){
      document.querySelector('.hello').style.display = 'block';
    }
  });
</script>
```

And I didn't even need to modify any code on the Qualtrics JS file.

Hope this will help someone who encounters the same issue!